# Execute Long running jobs from bottle web server

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, bottle

## What I am trying to do

I have a front end system that is generating output.  I am accessing this data(JSON) with a post request using bottle.  My post receives the json without issue.  I need to execute a backend python program(blender automation) and pass this JSON data to that program.

## What I have tried to do

#### Subprocess

- Using subprocess call the program and pass the input.  In appearance seems to execute but when i check System Monitor the program is not starting but my server continues to run as it should.  This subprocess command runs perfectly fine when executed independently from the server.

blender, script, and json are all string objects with **absolute file paths**

```
sub = subprocess.Popen([blender + " -b -P " + script + " -- " + json], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)
```

#### C Style os.fork()

- Same as above which i found reading pydoc that subprocess operates using these methods

#### Double Fork

- From a posting on here tried forking from the server and then calling subprocess from that fork and terminating the parent of the subprocess to create an orphan.  My subprocess command still does not execute and never shows up in System Monitor.

## What I need

I need a solution that will run from the bottle server in its own process.  It will handle multiple requests so the subprocess cannot block in the server.  The process being called is fully automated and just requires sending the JSON data in the execution command.  The result of the subprocess program will be string path to a file created on the server.

The above subprocess works perfectly fine when called from my test driver program.  I just need to connect the execution to the webservice so my front end can trigger its execution.

My bottle post method - prints json when called without issue.

```
@post('/getData')
def getData():
    json_text = request.json
    print(json_text)
```

I am not sure where to go from here.  From what i have read thus far, subprocess should work.  Any help or suggestions would be very much appreciated.  If additional information is needed please let me know.  I will edit with more details.  Thank you.

Relevant Information:
OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS,
Python 3.x

## *EDIT

This isn't an elegant solution but my subprocess call works now.

```
cmd = blender
cmd += " -b -P "
cmd += script
cmd += " -- "
cmd += str(json)
sub = subprocess.Popen([cmd], shell=True)
```

It seems by setting shell=True and removing the stdout, stderr=PIPE allowed me to see output where i was throwing an unhandled exception because my json data was a list and not a string.

Comment: I'm curious: what makes you think you need a separate process?

Comment: @ron.rothman tbh I thought that is the correct way to handle this problem.

Comment: I attempted to run directly without a sub process and it still did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using python for executing your scripts a process created by Popen.subprocess  will unintentionally inherited and keeps open a file descriptor.

You need to close that so that process can run independently. **(close_fds=True)**

```
subprocess.Popen(['python', "-u", Constant.WEBAPPS_FOLDER + 'convert_file.py', src, username], shell=False, bufsize=-1, close_fds=True)
```

Alsso, u dont have to use shell for creating another process. It might have unintended [consequences](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments).

I had the exact same problem where bottle was not returning/hangs. It works now.

Comment: Interesting.  I will modify the code and see what happens with that.  That sound much more elegant than the solution I found.  Thank you